# Container decreases width instead of shrink proportionally when I change window width with Dev Tools

Tags: html, css

The container has a fixed width of 40 rem when the window width is smaller than 1000px.  When I continue to shrink the window width, I notice the container width decreases as well. What I try to achieve is to maintain container width and shrink proportionally. I double-checked my length unit; I do not use `vw` as a length unit. Thanks for helping me! Happy New Year Everyone!

Additionally, I notice that I need to work for browser compatibility as well. For example, I am using `transform`, and I probably also need to add `-webkit-transform` whenever I use it. Is there any way I can add these things automatically? Or I have to remember all CSS properties that work for other browsers engines?

Here is the corresponding JsFiddle file.
https://jsfiddle.net/862vhz4f/

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  --large-font-size: 4rem;
  --medium-font-size: 1.75rem;
  --small-font-size: 1.8rem;
  --soft-violet-color: hsl(273, 75%, 66%);
  --soft-blue-color: hsl(240, 73%, 65%);
  --color-light-grayish-blue: hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
  --color-dark-grayish-blue: hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
  --color-very-dark-grayish-blue: hsl(237, 12%, 33%);
  --color-soft-red: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
  font-size: 50%;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, var(--soft-violet-color), var(--soft-blue-color));
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 18rem;
    padding-bottom: 8rem;
  }
}


/* #############Overall container CSS################# */

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 110rem;
  min-height: 64rem;
  background: url('./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg'), white;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background-position: -72rem -37.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 40rem;
    box-shadow: 0 5rem 5rem -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background: url('./images/bg-pattern-mobile.svg'), white;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}


/* #############Side svg CSS################# */

.svg_container {
  position: relative;
}

.cube_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.75rem;
  left: -11.5rem;
  animation: dropCub 2.5s infinite;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .cube_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5.5rem;
    left: 50%;
    width: 12rem;
    margin-left: -15.5rem;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

.women_container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.women__img {
  margin-top: 10rem;
  margin-left: -9.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .women__img {
    width: 30rem;
    margin-top: -13.75rem;
  }
  .women_container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: visible;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(5rem);
  }
}


/* #############FAQ CSS################# */

.faq_content_container {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 9rem 0;
  padding-right: 7rem;
  padding-left: 4.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .faq_content_container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9rem 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
  }
  .faq_title {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.faq_title {
  font-size: var(--large-font-size);
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.faq {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-light-grayish-blue);
}

.faq__question {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 4rem;
  outline: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: var(--color-very-dark-grayish-blue);
  font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .faq__question {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
}

.faq__question:hover {
  color: var(--color-soft-red);
}


/* Remove unnecessary arrow for the details tag */

.faq__question::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

.faq[open] .faq__question {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.faq__question::after {
  content: url('./images/icon-arrow-down.svg');
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .faq__question::after {
    right: 0;
  }
}

.faq__answer {
  color: var(--color-dark-grayish-blue);
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}


/* #############footer CSS################# */

.attribution {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%);
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: white;
}


/* #############footer CSS################# */

@keyframes dropCub {
  0% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  50% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
    transform: translateY(-1rem);
  }
  100% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" />

  <title>Frontend Mentor | FAQ Accordion Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="svg_container">
      <img src="./images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" alt="cube" class="cube_img" />
      <div class="women_container">
        <img src="./images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" alt="desktop women" class="women__img" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="faq_content_container">
      <h1 class="faq_title">FAQ</h1>
      <div class="faqs_container">
        <details class="faq">
          <summary class="faq__question">
            How many team members can I invite?
          </summary>
          <p class="faq__answer">
            You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
          </p>
        </details>

        <details open class="faq">
          <summary class="faq__question">
            What is the maximum file upload size?
          </summary>
          <p class="faq__answer">
            No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
          </p>
        </details>

        <details class="faq">
          <summary class="faq__question">
            How do I reset my password?
          </summary>
          <p class="faq__answer">
            Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.
          </p>
        </details>

        <details class="faq">
          <summary class="faq__question">
            Can I cancel my subscription?
          </summary>
          <p class="faq__answer">
            Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
          </p>
        </details>

        <details class="faq">
          <summary class="faq__question">
            Do you provide additional support?
          </summary>
          <p class="faq__answer">
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
          </p>
        </details>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="attribution">
      Challenge by
      <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a
            >. Coded by <a href="#">shawn</a>.
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest you try using the “min-width” instead of just width to ensure your container doesn’t go below 40rem.

And as for the vendor prefixes, you could try using preprocessors like SASS or LESS. You just write your normal code and they do the compilation for you and add appropriate prefixes.